# How to attribute value to row based on nearest date

Tags: sql

I'm attempting to attribute a value for "revenue" to a row based on the closest run_date, looking forwards in time. I'm using a date range as a join condition to only join rows within a 10 day "lookahead" period with the below....

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM t1 
  INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
  AND t2.date BETWEEN t1.run_date AND DATE_ADD(t1.run_date, INTERVAL 10 DAY)
```

The far right table is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Does anybody have any advice as to how to get my intended result? (Far right table of the image)

I have a SQL fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9e44f7/1) if anyone is interested in helping out.

Comment: Not particularly useful but in MySql 8 a lateral join easily solves this.

Comment: Since SQL includes data definition, a [mcve] should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for sample tables and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data in the [question itself](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/90527). Note that adding a link to a live example *in addition* to having code in the question is welcomed. See the help center for more on [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and many other helpful topics.

Comment: [Images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) should not be used for textual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t1` needs to be compared to itself in order to find the `t1` row where `t2` belongs.  Do do so you need to join to `t1` twice.  You can put a sub-select to test for the existence of a more appropriate t1 into the condition of an `OUTER JOIN` as follows:

```
SELECT 
t1.id, c_id, run_date, coalesce(revenue,0) revenue
FROM t1 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
  AND t2.date BETWEEN t1.run_date AND DATE_ADD(t1.run_date, INTERVAL 10 DAY)
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 'X'
    FROM t1 as later
    WHERE t1.id = t2.id
    AND later.run_date < t2.date
    AND t1.run_date < later.run_date
)
ORDER BY run_date
```